# Symfony-like element prototype for Rails

Tags: symfony, ruby-on-rails-4

In Symfony you can use `allow_add` to add a `data-prototype` attribute to a parent element in your form. Is there a similar solution for Rails? I want to easily add elements to a form using javascript, and that prototype would make things much easier if the form elements change.